# CoCreateInstance returns SL_E_LICENSE_FILE_NOT_INSTALLED (0xc004f011)

Tags: windows, winapi, ole

Is the error referring to windows license? I have a valid one. 
This is on Windows 8.1.

Thanks,

Comment: Related to license for specific CLSID (feature) you are instantiating, what is the argument you are passing to the `CoCreateInstance` API?

Comment: What COM object are you trying to instantiate?